# Which macs are compatible with OS X 10.11 El Capitan?

Tags: hardware, macos

Is there a list of officially supported Macs for OS X El Capitan?

I ask to get ready if any hardware which is supported on Yosemite is not supported by El Capitan?

Comment: Isn't this question off-topic?  If I understand correctly, El Capitan is not released to the public, so it is explicitly out of scope for this site.  See our [help], specifically http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ("Please refrain from asking about.... Pre-release, non-publicly available beta software") and http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/1712/24154 ("No - OS X 10.11 El Capitan is not released to the public. ... As a rule, don't ask questions on software not publicly released.") and http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/1331/24154.  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Note that if you download El Capitan through Apple's public beta, Apple imposes a [NDA](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/legal) (a confidentiality requirement).  [Apple's requirements](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/faq) include: ~"The public beta software is Apple confidential information.  Don’t publicly post information about the public beta software, and don't discuss the public beta software with others who are not in the Apple Beta Software Program."~

Comment: @D.W. and others. We don't enforce NDA or other agreements, although many will down vote or wonder why people do violate them. Reputation is largely based on how trustworthy your answers are in the eyes of the subset of "the community" that choose to vote. FYI - The specs listed are not protected by NDA or log in since Apple published them on the open internet.

Comment: @bmike, I understand very well that we don't enforce NDAs... but that's not my point.  Both the FAQ and the Meta questions I linked to seem to have an explicit statement that places this question off-topic.  See http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: "Please refrain from asking about ... software granted only under an NDA".  That's why I mentioned the NDA: El Capitan is "software granted only under an NDA", so asking about it seems off-topic.  See also my other arguments.  How does this question not violate the rules set out in the [help] and in the questions that I linked to?

Comment: @D.W. Not all questions are off topic. To put a fine pontoon it, this is _about what Apple announced and not the OS itself_. **This is about hardware and if people can start planning for the fall**. It's not about using the new OS.  It would be best to discuss this specific question on [meta] if you would like more detail or discussion.

Comment: Now that El Capitan is shipping, should we rewrite this question and answers?  Conversely, should we rewrite the question "what Macs were compatible with El Capitan beta x.y"?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you care to read the tea leaves, the initial OS X v10.11 Developer Beta supports the following Macs:

- iMac (Mid 2007 or newer)
- MacBook Air (Late 2008 or newer)
- MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)
- Mac mini (Early 2009 or newer)
- MacBook Pro (Mid/Late 2007 or newer)
- Mac Pro (Early 2008 or newer)
- Xserve (Early 2009)

Source: [OS X v10.11 Developer Beta 1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/rn-osx-10.11/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016209).

No [official requirements](http://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-preview/) are published by Apple.

About your last question, no. There are no macs supported by Yosemite that are not supported by El Capitan.

Comment: Basically, it's the same list of hardware which was supported by Mac OS X 10.10.

Comment: There are now official requirements published by Apple. They match this answer. They can be found in [this support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475) and on the [El Capitan How to Install page](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/)

Answer (score 11):

It's worth noting that every Mac that supports Mountain Lion (10.8) also supports Mavericks (10.9), Yosemite (10.10), and El Capitan Developer Beta 1 (10.11). System requirements in El Capitan are unlikely to change from those in the developer beta.

However, some features might be unavailable on earlier systems. There is informed speculation that Metal, for example, might only work with newer GPUs.

Comment: Indeed Metal will probably be supported only on GPUs introduced since 2012: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191078/11600