# Which graphics cards or integrated GPUs support metal?

Tags: hardware, gpu, macos

Apple announced metal for OS X.

Apple's website clearly states some features will not be available on all macs, which seems to refer to metal support.

But is there a list of already confirmed GPUs, most importantly are intel integrated GPUs supported?

This would help me choosing a future dev computer with metal support this summer.

---

We know Metal on iOS is [linked](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html) to OpenGL ES 3.0 support. All devices which support OpenGL ES 3 also support Metal.

Is there a direct link between Metal support and a specific version of OpenGL (and maybe unrelated to graphics OpenCL)?

Comment: Let's see whether somebody digs out some publicly available information about this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the WWDC 2015 video "[What's new in Metal, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=603)", Rav Dhiraj from the GPU software division states at 8'40"

> Metal is supported by all Macs introduced since 2012. (Nvidia, AMD and Intel)

This means :

- Intel HD Graphics 4000, Iris 5000 & 6000 family,
- nVidia GT 600M, 700M family,
- AMD R9 M family,

Comment: Doesn't it coincide with OpenCL compatible GPU drivers?

Comment: Not exactely : https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202823  It's probably with openGL 4/OpenCL 1.2

Comment: Perfect! I just watched the keynote and this is exactly what they say: all configurations since 2012 across the 3 vendors (intel, nvidia, amd).

Answer (score 2):

I'm running a mac pro 3,1 with a gtx 760 card (kepler based) and according to the metalinfo app released by netkas it is metal supported:

MetalInfo!
Metal Device Name:  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760
Lower Power Device: No
Headless Device:    Yes
logout
Saving session...completed.

Turns out all you need is a modern graphics card!